# Adding two container views to a view controller

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uicontainerview

I have added two container views into a stack view but can only see one of the containers contents when i run the simulator. Are there any special considerations for attempting this? Is it possible? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's quite possible. You have to control-drag from each container view to the child view controller that you want to embed in each, and if you have custom setup code for each you need to put unique segue identifiers on each and write your `prepareForSegue` method to set up each separately.

Post your code and screenshots of your IB setup for more specific help.